# Android-betterpickers inclusion issue

Tags: android

I'm trying to use this project as a library in my project: https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers

I'm having some issues with it though. It has errors as soon as I import the project. Do I need to include other libraries within the project to get it to compile? The usage states that the requirements are android 14+, which I've met.

Comment: Did it occur to you to maybe post (some of) the errors you encounter? And, incidentally, the IDE you're using, even though it's probably eclipse.

Comment: It says I'm missing a few libraries, such as the support library. But if the usage states that android 14+ is required, how does this make sense? After I download/incorporate the proper libraries, it compiles but when I try to include it in my main project, I get erros in my main project. Additionally, the instructions seem to indicate that the library is plug-and-play.

Comment: In my experience, problems like this are often solved by going to Project properties -> Android and then selecting a working Project build target.